# Has anyone ever encountered additional unknown characters appending to your column entries after importing from a .csv file?

Tags: mysql

I've filled my table of instruments using LOAD INTO FILE. It fills the rows successfully but then doesn't enclose the final column (status) with a vertical line. I didn't think this was an issue until I ran a query to check the number of column entries = "commissioning".

> SELECT COUNT(*)
> FROM instrument
> WHERE status = 'commissioning';

**All 60 rows contain "commissioning" so it should return 60, but instead it returns 0?**

[I retried the query with a wildcard search and returned the right result here (You can also see the table is not enclosed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyqlI.png)

Perhaps something is going on when I imported from csv file, because a LENGTH(status) query returns 14 when "commissioning" is only 13 characters. Has anyone encountered this before or know what character could be causing this?

[Heres the import from the csv file code for further clarity - but it worked fine with my other tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIwzU.png)

Comment: If you are using windows,  your CSV lines may finish with `\r\n`instead of `\n`only. Try importing again but use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`

Comment: Thank you Nacho this was the answer! My statement is working and it also fixed the unusual enclosure behaviour, I'm new to SO, so unsure how I credit this comment as the solution, but thank you!

Comment: Ok, i will put the comment as an answer so you can upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is produced because Windows uses `'\r\n'` instead of `'\n'`. As you are telling the import statement to finish lines with `'\n'` you have an extra `'\r'` character in every line. You need to change your import statement as:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'instruments.csv'
INTO TABLE instruments
FILEDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```